# Create UITableViewCellAccessory during editing

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Attached is a screen shot from the iPhone Recipes Core Data source example.

I'm trying to recreate the display of the three horizontal lines in the UITableViewCellAccessory position during editing, but I can't see any UITableViewCellAccessory style that would create three horizontal lines.  During editing, the source code sets the accessory style to UITableViewCellAccessoryStyleNone.

Can you give me a hint on how to create this effect?

[image: UITableViewCell during editing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three horizontal lines are for moving the table cells.  The following code should enable them for you using the `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
     return YES;
}
```

You should also implement the `tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` to give the style and indentation you want while the cell is in edit mode.  Example outline code below:

```
// Override to prevent/allow indentation of cells in editing mode
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

// Select the editing style of each cell
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Do not allow inserts / deletes
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Hope this helps; please mark this answer as correct if it's what you're looking for.